# how to fit a asp.net datalist control inside a html table row

Tags: asp.net, html, css, datalist

I created a asp.net web page and I have a html table 16 columns wide with a datalist control on every column. I need to give the look of a gridview control, (One column of data next to the other) but somehow there is a lot of white space in the Table Column around the datalist controls, how can I reduce this to the minimum so each column show next to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the width of your outer table set to 100%.
Perhaps a dump of the markup would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

### That will help:

```
<Table Style="padding:0px; cell-spacing:0px;">
...
</table>
```